# Copy .bak file to another Windows server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

I have `.bak` files that created by a job on SQL Server every night. I want the `.bak` file to be copied to another server. I created a job running the command

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'copy "G:\Source\folder\file.bak" "\\destination\Work\folder\"'
```

but the job creates the a copy of the `.bak` file on the source machine but in different directory.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is `Destination` the name of the second server?

Comment: It works for me, try this `'copy "G:\Source\folder\file.bak" "\\destination\Work\folder\file.bak"'`

Comment: Does the account that SQL Server runs under even have access permissions to that remote server?